# Why is index.php/login.php accepted as a valid url?

Tags: php, html, web, iis-7

I did some pentesting on a website I am helping a client with and the tools reported that there are URLs like /index.php/login.php which might be vulnerable to something. The problem is that since it is a simple php site, normally this kind of URL shouldn't be possible (there is no folder "index.php" which contains a file "login.php"). I guess I could set some filter for the URL to clean this and redirect to the first php file.
The actual effect of these urls is that the browser goes in a infinite loop requesting all the files over and over ...
The site is using framesets (unfortunately) and I feel like it has something to do with this, but can't find a fix for it ...

Using IIS7 with php 5.3.63

Comment: is there any URL rewriting, for example with an .htaccess file, active in the site? This URL could be valid if rewritten

Comment: no, nothing. Initially I suspected this is the default behavior of IIS, but now I am looking into the framesets

Comment: PHP 5.3 is long dead. `index.php/login.php` can be valid (where `login.php` can be treated as path info, https://users.cs.fiu.edu/~downeyt/webdev/path.info.html), so it would be yourself to properly handle it.

Comment: @LexLi thanks. That was it! Unfortunately I can't update the php version. I have fixed it using IIS' URL Rewrite module.